# how to change background colour of fb likebox?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

in my blog I add a fb like box. but I would like to change the background colour from transparente to white. can anybody help me?

this is the java script

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and this is the code for plug in

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/paritambo" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div>
```

thank you

Comment: Fb likebox plugins got a option called "color scheme" ( light and dark ). Note that the background is always transparent to match your background color. This setting changes the foreground colors to work well on light or dark backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but still: there is a way to change to background colour by changing the css-code, but i dont know how to do it. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your FB likebox is transparent. You can wrap it with a div and specify a color for the wrapping div and it will change the color of the background

Comment: thanks for the reply. but I really have no clue about it. how does it work with this div?

Comment: try this: <div style="background-color:red"><div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/paritambo" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div></div>

Comment: you might need to style the enclosing div a bit. I ran into the same problem around the same time as you and i did something like this to change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old question, I think I can explain this and others might find it useful.

When you get the Facebook like box code from Facebook developers, it is already wrapped inside a div element with class name `"fb-like-box"`.

Now, just modify your style-sheet to customize this div.

You can modify its background-color and size like any other div, but not its inner content.

Hope this helps you.